# bxSlider resizes properly on desktop but is not working on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, bxslider

Relatively green web developer here: There is a "responsive" jquery bxslider carousel implemented on a site I am looking at which scales and functions properly on desktop computers and when resizing the page on desktop, but the it does not work on mobile/tablets. Instead of placing the images in a slider carousel, it stacks the images one on top of another. I see the same problem when I use Chrome's "inspect element" tool to toggle to mobile devices.

When I inspect the element in, for example, an iphone6 device mode, the divs immediately following the ".bx-slider" div do not have the class of "bx-viewport" like they do when inspecting the element at a desktop resolution when the slider works. I suspect this has something to do with the problem, but I'm unsure as to where this is going wrong in the code.

Below is some jquery which creates "clones" relating to the slider. I apologize that I don't have much insight on the problem as I didn't build the page.

```
    w = $(window).width();
    h = $(window).outerHeight();

    // Adaptive Slider
    switch(true) {
        case (w > 1190):
               minimum = 3;
               maximum = 3;
               width = 5000;
               margin = 3;
            infinite = false;
            hide = true;
            currentState = "desktop";
              break;
              case (w < 1190 && w > 767):
               minimum = 2;
               maximum = 2;
               width = 5000;
               margin = 20;
            infinite = false;
            hide = true;
            currentState = "tablet";
              break;
              default:
               minimum = 1;
               maximum = 1;
               width = 5000;
               margin = 0;
            infinite = false;
            hide = true;
            currentState = "mobile";
    }
    var mySettings = {
        touchEnabled: true,
        auto  : false,
        autoHover : false,
        pager : true,
        minSlides: minimum,
        maxSlides: maximum,
        slideWidth: width,
        slideMargin: margin,
        infiniteLoop: infinite,
        hideControlOnEnd: hide,
        onSlideBefore : removePlayer,
        onSlideAfter : removePlayer
    }
    clearTimeout(id);
    id = setTimeout(function(){
        if (!adaptLoaded) {
            $(".bx-adapt").each(function(i) {
                slider["adapt"][i] = $(this).bxSlider(mySettings);
            });
            adaptLoaded = true;
            loadedState = currentState;
        } else if (loadedState != currentState) {
            for (var i = 0; i < slider["adapt"].length; i++) {
                slider["adapt"][i].reloadSlider(mySettings);
            };
            loadedState = currentState;
        }
    }, 500);


    // Tablet Slider
    tabletSettings = {
        touchEnabled: true,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        auto  : false,
        autoHover : false,
        pager : true,
        onSlideBefore : removePlayer,
        onSlideAfter : removePlayer
    };
    if (w > 1183){
        if (tabletLoaded){
            for (var i = 0; i < slider["tablet"].length; i++) {
                destroySlider(slider["tablet"][i]);
                slider["tablet"][i].replaceWith(tabletClone[i].clone(true,true));
            };
               tabletLoaded = false;
             }
    } else {
        if (!tabletLoaded){
            $(".bx-tablet").each(function(i) {
                tabletClone[i] = jQuery($(this)).clone(true,true);
                slider["tablet"][i] = $(this).bxSlider(tabletSettings);
            });
            tabletLoaded = true;
        };
    };

    // Mobile Slider
    mobileSettings = {
        touchEnabled: true,
        infiniteLoop: false,
        hideControlOnEnd: true,
        auto  : false,
        autoHover : false,
        pager : true
    };
    if (w > 767){
        if (mobileLoaded){
           for (var i = 0; i < slider["mobile"].length; i++) {
                slider["mobile"][i].destroySlider();
                slider["mobile"][i].replaceWith(mobileClone[i].clone(true, true));
            };
            mobileLoaded = false;
        }
    }else{
        if (!mobileLoaded){
            $(".bx-mobile").each(function(i) {
                mobileClone[i] = jQuery($(this)).clone(true, true);
                slider["mobile"][i] = $(this).bxSlider(mobileSettings);
            });
            mobileLoaded = true;
        }
    };
```

I know people will be asking for a JSfiddle to duplicate the problem but the site in question is a rather robust drupal site and replicating it would be impossible. However, I will provide any code that is requested.

Comment: In desktop mode, bxSlider operates as expected with this code?

Comment: Yep, everything scales and functions properly in desktop mode. Actually, some sliders glitch in Chrome and create extra invisible slides but I think that's a story for another day.

Comment: I have the exact problem now, did you find the problem by any chance?